Where is e field length, which is implicitly a member of every array type?
how can I find length property in runtime during debuging for example. its just for curiosity.
    int[] array = {5, 3, 8, 2, 1, 9, 4, 7, 6};

    int nn = array.length;

in the java especification says: "› The field length, which is implicitly a member of every array type (§10.7)
"
but where is it in the code of the JDK ? It is created just in runtime?


length is only a member field of array types as far as the Java Language is concerned. Under the hood, it's just a arraylength instruction in bytecode. For more info see the duplicate target.

Really, the only time it makes sense to use reflection to access an array length is when you don't know (for sure) that it must be an array. Basically almost never. But to prove it's possible, and what is really going on consider Object array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; System.out.println(java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(array));
